# Error TS2688 Build:Cannot find type definition file for 'mocha' after TypeScript update

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, angular, typescript, asp.net-core

I, am keep getting the **error: Cannot find type definition file for 'mocha'** when I update the TypeScript to latest version.

**tsconfig.json**

```
    {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "rootDir": "app",
    "outDir": "wwwroot/app"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot/node_modules",
    "typings"

  ]
}
```

I, have not change any things. It was working perfectly earlier just I update the TypeScript version from 2.2.2 to 2.5 and keep getting error. I, am using Angular 4

**Package.json**

```
    {
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "asp.net",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.20",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.9",
    "rxjs": "5.0.2",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "typescript": "^2.4.1",
    "zone.js": "0.7.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to install type definitions for mocha:

```
npm install @types/mocha
```

Comment: where should I install this type. Is it in global or to the specific folder of project\

Comment: does not get rid of the issue - Cannot find type definition file for 'mocha'

Comment: It fix one problem and gives the following additional error in @jest

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue on `@nestjs/microservice` and it is fixed on upgrading it to `6.5.1` 
Please check the issue [here](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/2534)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using yarn package manager:

```
yarn add --dev mocha
```